# FileSystem Provider Error in the Get-ChildItem Implementation of the Filter Parameter?

Tags: powershell

Recently I was to create a report via PowerShell about the `*.inf` files located in the `C:\Windows\winsxs` folder unsing the `Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` (see the official documentation about [this cmdlet and its parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)), like:

```
$infFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\winsxs -Filter *.inf -Recurse
```

I've noticed it however, that files having other file extensions, like `.inf_loc` or `.inf_dbf42768` are included in the result as well.

On the other hand, the `Include` parameter works as expected, returning only the `.inf` files:

```
$infFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\winsxs -Include *.inf -Recurse
```

I've tested the phenomenon using PS version 3 and 4, and found, that if the extension you are looking for has exactly 3 character, than any files, those extensions begin with the same 3 character are returned, even if those files have a longer extension. If the extension you are looking for is shorter or longer than 3 characters, there is no such issue, at least, based on my experience.

Although performance is in my case not crucial, as far as I understand, using the `Filter` parameter would be more efficient, than the `Include` parameter, as it performs the filtering already on the provider level, as discussed in the [cmdlet description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

> Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider
>   applies them when retrieving the objects, rather than having Windows
>   PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved.

and [here](https://tfl09.blogspot.co.at/2012/02/get-childitem-and-theinclude-and-filter.html):

> ...the –Filter parameter generates early, early filtering,
>   whereas-Include is later early filtering! The performance difference
>   between the two approaches turns out to be significant!

Is it a documented behaviour / bug? I've found something similar in [the post mentioned before](https://tfl09.blogspot.co.at/2012/02/get-childitem-and-theinclude-and-filter.html) as well, but not in the official documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Per the linked question, this seems like a limitation of the `-Filter` parameter. I guess another solution would be to still use `-Filter` for its performance benefit but then filter out the extra results you don't want afterwards with `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter "*.inf" | where {$_ -match "\.inf$"}
```

This uses the regex `$` character to return only where `.inf` is at the end of the string.